# Create slide animation by remove one UIView and then add another UIView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, animation, uiview

I have view that has a webview and a UIToolbar.

I want to create an animation that performs a "kCATransitionFromTop" transition by first remove the the previous webview, and then add a new webView to the superView.
During this transition, I want the toolbar to stay whatever the position it is at right now and NOT move.

Code:
Add the toolbar

```
toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] init]; 
toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;
toolbar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[toolbar setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 480 - 88 - 20, 320.0, 44)];
//Add the toolbar as a subview to the navigation controller. 
[self.view addSubview:toolbar];
```

Animation:

```
UIView *currentView = webView;
UIView *theWindow = [currentView superview];

UIView *newView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, self.view.bounds.size.height - self.navigationController.toolbar.frame.size.height)];
newView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

// remove the current view and replace with new view
[currentView removeFromSuperview];
[theWindow insertSubview:newView belowSubview:toolbar];

// set up the animation 
CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
[animation setDuration:0.4];
[animation setType:kCATransitionPush];
[animation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromTop];
[animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];

[[theWindow layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"PushNextArticleView"];
```

Everything seems to work out ok, except the toolbar is moving with the webview as well...
What did I do wrong and how can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't you mean to only apply the transition to the `layer` of `newView`?

```
[[newView layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"PushNextArticleView"];
```

Comment: Thanks, that solved the problem; however, there is a black hole now between the transition. I suppose the removeFromSuperview is not animted?

Comment: Correct. Set yourself as the layer's delegate and implement `-animationDidStop:finished:`. This will be messaged when the animation stops, then you can remove the original view from its superview.

Comment: When i comment out [currentView removeFromSuperview]; , somehow the views refuse to perform the animation now. It seems they don'like insertSubview method..If i tell it to AddSubview, the animation will be fine.....

Comment: I don't know why but by adding " [self.view bringSubviewToFront:toolbar];" fixed the animation... Which library do I need to import to make CAAnimationDelegate work?

Comment: I think misunderstand this delegate. It's working now, thanks!